# Wait for updateMany inside forEach loop to run and then return response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

I'm new to javascript and i'm having a hard time making my response return to wait for my mongodb query finish running inside a forEach loop.

My code is currrently:

```
exports.applyThesaurus = (req, res, next) => {
  let numModified = 0;
  var prom = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
   req.file.forEach((obj,idx) => {
    wos.updateMany(
      { creator: req.userData.userId},
      { $set: { [req.body.field+".$[element]"] : obj.replaceWith } },
      { arrayFilters: [ {  "element": { $in:  obj.replaced } } ] }
    ).then((result) => {
      console.log(result.nModified)
      numModified += result.nModified
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json('There was an error while applying the thesaurus.');
    })

      if( idx === req.file.length -1) {
        resolve()
      }
   })
 })
 prom.then(() => {
  console.log('im returning');
  res.status(200).json({message: numModified + ' itens replaced successfully'});
 })
}
```

What happens is that the "i'm returning" console log triggers before the one logging result.nModified

I need to be able to run all the updateMany queries and then respond with the number of updated itens.

Any tips? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is trying to return resolve before your `updateMany` executes.

```js
if (idx === req.file.length - 1) {
  resolve() // this resolve get's executed befour updateMany get executed
}
```

this might give you a better understanding of the [callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442321/callback-function-example) and why it is happening. as said if you want to resolve the promise after your `updateMany` finishes execution you need to update your code as below:

```js
exports.applyThesaurus = (req, res, next) => {
    let numModified = 0;
    var prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let updateManyPromisesArray = []
        req.file.forEach((obj, idx) => {
            updateManyPromisesArray.push(wos.updateMany({
                creator: req.userData.userId
            }, {
                $set: {
                    [req.body.field + ".$[element]"]: obj.replaceWith
                }
            }, {
                arrayFilters: [{
                    "element": {
                        $in: obj.replaced
                    }
                }]
            }))

            Promise.all(updateManyPromisesArray)
                .then((result) => {
                    if (idx === req.file.length - 1) {
                        resolve()
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    res.status(500).json('There was an error while applying the thesaurus.');
                })
        })
    })


    prom.then(() => {
        console.log('im returning');
        res.status(200).json({
            message: numModified + ' itens replaced successfully'
        });
    })
}
```

Also, you should start using [async and await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44512388/understanding-async-await-on-nodejs) for avoiding these kinds of [callback hells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098066/what-is-callback-hell-and-how-and-why-does-rx-solve-it) situations.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it still doesn't fully wait for all the updateMany queries. Before it would execute the "im returning" first but now it executes after 3~5 queries ran but not after all. I'll take a look in the async await you sent, i also tried some with it but no luck.

Comment: have you tried using [Promise.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38180080/when-to-use-promise-all) ?@jay2p

Comment: also, try running the above snippet I have updated it with the `Promise.all()`

Comment: Hey, looks like its now executing the "im returning" last. I added the numModified += resut.nModified back before the IF with the resolve (i think you accidentaly removed it) but now its always undefined. EDIT: Just realized the result is now an array, i'll loop through it and sum the numbers. Thank you very much.

Comment: it's returning `undefined` because `result` is not an object anymore. it's an array of objects. so you need to loop through `result` and handle your success and errors accordingly.