# How to refactor this code more optimistically using Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, es6-promise, promise.all

**How do we implement the below code using Promise.all() ?**
**I have tried using promise,async/await way. But, this problem requires something to be done using Promise.all()**

```js
class Provider{
  /*
  Gets the weather for a given city
  */
  static getWeather(city){
    return Promise.resolve(`The weather of ${city} is cloudy`)
  };
  /*
  Gets the weather for a given city
  */
  static getLocalCurrency(city){
    return Promise.resolve(`The local currency of ${city} is GBP`)
  };
  /*
  Gets the Longitude and Latitude, this function returns a city
  */
  static findCity(long,lat){
    return Promise.resolve(`London`)
  };
  
};
```

```js
//my implamentation;

let fnCall = async () => {
  let city = await Provider.findCity(0.1278,51.5074);
  let cityWeather = await Provider.getWeather(city);
  let cityCurrency = await Provider.getLocalCurrency(city);
  
  console.log(city);
  console.log(cityWeather);
  console.log(cityCurrency);
} 

fnCall();
```

Comment: Not possible, because each subsequent call depends on the previous

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Not necessarily  - see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38188638/2570277)

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to serially chain the dependant API calls , (output of one is input to next) and streamline/pipe the independent calls parallelly.

Rest if you're interested to stick to async await sugar-coated syntax , see below snippet example.

```js
class Provider{
  /*
  Gets the weather for a given city
  */
  static getWeather(city){
return Promise.resolve(`The weather of ${city} is cloudy`)
  };
  /*
  Gets the weather for a given city
  */
  static getLocalCurrency(city){
return Promise.resolve(`The local currency of ${city} is GBP`)
  };
  /*
  Gets the Longitude and Latitude, this function returns a city
  */
  static findCity(long,lat){
return Promise.resolve(`London`)
  };
  
};

let fnCall = async () => {
let city = await Provider.findCity(0.1278,51.5074);
let [cityWeather, cityCurrency] = await Promise.all([Provider.getWeather(city),Provider.getLocalCurrency(city)]);
  
console.log(city);
console.log(cityWeather);
console.log(cityCurrency);
} 

fnCall();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `Promise.all` from the outset because the 2nd and 3rd are dependent on the first.  But you can still chain them, using `Promise.all` on the inner, and passing the city result to the end of the chain.

```
let fnCall = async () => {
  return await Provider
    .findCity(0.1278,51.5074)
    .then(city => {
      return Promise.all([
        city,
        Provider.getWeather(city),
        Provider.getLocalCurrency(city)
      ])
    .then(([city, weather, currency]) => {
      console.log(city);
      console.log(weather);
      console.log(currency);
    })
} 

fnCall();
```

Comment: Okay Dave, Thank you very much for your approach and suggestion.

Comment: Please don't mix `async`/`await` with `.then()` calls like this

Comment: Care to explain why not?