# Javascript Promise - spread and add other methods

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to make the following function?

```
const method = () => {
    let _reject;
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      _reject = reject;
      ...
    });
  
    return {
      ...promise,
      cancel: () => _reject('cancelled'),
    }
}
```

i.e. I can do something like:

```
const promise = method();
// now I have promise.then, promise.catch and promise.cancel
```

This is just an example; I want to be able to add extra properties to this "promise" object.

Comment: Keep in mind that this hypothetical `cancel()` method doesn't actually terminate the asynchronous code initiated by the promise constructor.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't spread a promise instance, as it would loose its prototype (methods), but you can trivially add properties to it like to any object:

```
promise.cancel = () => _reject('cancelled');
return promise;
```

<sub>(Note that I'm not saying this is a good idea)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

See this answer [Extending a Promise in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792036/extending-a-promise-in-javascript)

you might need extend your specialized Promise class

```js
class CancellablePromise extends Promise {
   cancel(){ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
const _resolve= Symbol('resolve');
const _reject= Symbol('reject');

class ExPromise extends Promise{
    constructor(executor) {
        let resolve, reject;

        super((_resolve, _reject) => {
            resolve = _resolve;
            reject = _reject;
            executor(resolve, reject);
        });

        this[_resolve]= resolve;
        this[_reject]= reject;
    }

    cancel(){
        this[_reject](new Error('canceled'));
    }
}
```

If you need cancellation of the nested promises or some other extra features, you can try the [c-promise2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2) package