# TypeScript / JavaScript: How to wrap a Promise object using decorator pattern

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I'm attempting to wrap a TypeScript (JavaScript) Promise object with the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) because I need to add additional logic inside the Promise's `then` and `catch` methods (not shown here).

So far, it looks like this:

```
export class Decorator {
    protected _promise: Promise<any>;

    constructor(promise: Promise<any>) {
        this._promise = promise;
    }

    then(onFulfilled: any, onRejected: any): Promise<any> {
        return this._promise.then(r => onFulfilled(r), r => onRejected(r))
    };

    catch(onRejected: any): Promise<any> {
        return this._promise.catch(r => onRejected(r));
    }
}

(async () {
    // Note that doSomethingAsynchronously() returns a Promise<void>
    await new Decorator(doSomethingAsynchronously()); // ERROR!!
})();
```

However, as noted by the "ERROR!!" comment above, I get this build error:

> Type of "await" operand must either be a valid promise or must not contain a callable "then" member.

I've tried experimenting with extending Promise (hence the class declaration would become `export class Decorator<T> extends Promise<T>`), but then I have to call `super()` in the constructor and pass it an executor object, which changes the Decorator class substantially. I'd like to avoid needing an executor, and would like to simply pass the inner promise into the constructor.

How can I successfully await the Decorator class's wrapped promise?

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?  Please describe and show that code and then we can better offer ways to solve the actual problem rather than just try to comment on the particular path you've chosen to go down which may not be the best way to go.  FYI, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), the way you've described it which should be avoided here.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41792036/extending-a-promise-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to accomplish and I agree with @jfriend00. Maybe asking what you are really trying to solve maybe you can get a better answer.

Anyway here is a way to do what you want... not sure if this is the best way... but it works...

```
class Decorator {
    protected _promise: Promise<any>;


    constructor(promise: Promise<any>) {
        this._promise = promise;
    }

    getPromise(onFulfilled?: any, onRejected?: any): Promise<any> {
      return this._promise.then(r => {
        console.log('Decorator:onFulfilled');
        onFulfilled(r);
      })
      .catch(r => {
        console.log('Decorator:onRejected');
        onRejected(r);
      })
    }
}

(async () => {
    // Note that doSomethingAsynchronously() returns a Promise<void>
    const doSomethingAsynchronouslyWithSuccess = () => {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
      });
    }
    const doSomethingAsynchronouslyWithFail = () => {
      return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => reject(), 1000);
      });
    }
    await new Decorator(doSomethingAsynchronouslyWithSuccess()).getPromise();
    await new Decorator(doSomethingAsynchronouslyWithFail()).getPromise();
})();
```