# Handling an array of promises from Promise.all

Tags: node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'm still fairly new to promises, and all the roads on what I'm currently doing lead me to `Promise.all()`, but I'm not sure how to handle the results.

I have some data like this

```
let data = {
  "format_oid":["35474527960032","2595837960032"]
};
```

I then pass it to a function like

**server.js**

```
jobHandler.handle(data)
  .then((info) => {
    console.log(info);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Within my `jobHandler` class I have

**jobHandler.js**

```
class Handler {
  // constructor etc
  handle(data) {
    return this.extract(data);
  }

  extract(data) {
    let request = data.format_oid.map( (releaseId) => {
      return this._getReleaseId(releaseId);
     });
     return Promise.all(request);
  }

  _getReleaseId(releaseId) {
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
      if (_hasRelease(releaseId)){
        resolve('yay');
      } else {
        reject('boo');
      }
    });
}
```

Currently `request` will have an array of Promises like `[ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]`

how would I then handle this array of promises in my **server.js**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One promise resolves with one result. `Promise.all()` resolves to an array of results, one result for each promise that was in the original array of promises in the same order as the promises.

> how would I then handle this array of promises in my server.js?

```
aHandlerObject.extract(data).then(results => {
   // results is an array of resolved values
   // one for each call to this._getReleaseId(...)
}).catch(err => {
   // handle error here
});
```

Comment: Am I missing something?  This seems to be the same code I have already?  Hmm I think I've asked the wrong question.  If one of my data returns 'yay' and the other 'boo', yay never seems to be output with my current code.  I think i need a new question for this.

Comment: Further reading seems to suggest that Promise.all will flunk out as soon as the array of promises has a rejection and not display any of the resolved values for that array...

Comment: @Jarede - You  asked a question (which I show in yellow in my answer) and I answered that for you.  It seemed to me that you were asking how the result from `Promise.all()` worked and how you would use it so that's what I answered.

Comment: @Jarede - As for the specific behavior of `Promise.all()`, it will reject immediately if any promise you pass it rejects.  If you want a different behavior, you can either intercept any of your promises with a `.catch()` on them individually to turn a reject into a resolve or you can use some code that does that for you: [ES6 Promise.all() error handle - Is .settle() needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605253/es6-promise-all-error-handle-is-settle-needed/36605453#36605453)

Comment: Yep @jfriend00 I asked the wrong question initially.  My bad.  I'm still fairly new to promises so still a bit to figure out.  That link helps, though i ended up using an answer from the duplicate question flag.  Cheers though.