# Adding timeout to promise that hangs

Tags: javascript, promise

Im using a promise for a child process that does not have it's own timeout. I've tried Promise Bluebird's `race` method, it is throwing but still hanging the console.

```
const done = () => Promise.delay(500).then(() => throw new Error('timeout')
const fire = () => Promise.race([promiseHangs(url), done()])
fire().then(console.log)
```

How can I resolve the `promiseHangs` promise and stop the async process from running?

Comment: Might be relevant: [Setting a timeout for each promise within a `Promise.all()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48577702/setting-a-timeout-for-each-promise-within-a-promise-all/48578424#48578424).

Comment: The code you hsve posted is concerned with how the  promise returned from `promiseHangs()` is used. Resolving that promise is all to do with how `promiseHangs()` is written. The question cannot be anwered.

Answer (score 1):

The result of `const done = () => Promise.delay(500).then(() => throw new Error('timeout')` is a thrown error. You are better off returning an actually promise from that using `Promise.reject('timeout')`

According to the documentation, the `Promise.any` method will return the first result and won't allow a rejected value you to win.

So `const fire = () => Promise.any([promiseHangs(url), done()])` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I never used it that way.